# Centreon Web Interface Slow

Tags: interface, nagios

Our Centreon web interface is so slow ! about 3/4 mins to have my click's results ...
While Nagios is working perfectly ...

Thanks to Google, i guess it comes from mysql. But I can't understand anything with it ...

If someone already solve this, would be perfect !

P.S : also posted on [centreon forum](http://forum.centreon.com/showthread.php/14493-Centreon-s-Interface-is-SO-slow-Affichage-Centreon-extr%C3%83%C2%A8mement-lent), and [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/527540/centreon-web-interface-slow)

Comment: I can't add : "Hi all", at the beginning of my post =/

Comment: Ooops. Don't cross post to other Stack sites like Serverfault. That usually gets someones panties in a twist!

Comment: I haven't used Centreon much, but when I ran it, it was a resource hog. To get it to be more responsive, I had to dedicate up to 4 or 6GB of RAM to the machine.

Comment: I don't know why, but everything's ok now ! We just restart when when deleted snapshots. So guess it comes from the VV of the ESXi... Sorry for the multiples post. Regards.

Comment: VMWare recommends against leaving snapshots around for a long period of time because it will impact performance significantly. The more snapshots the worse it is.